# Navigation menu scroll down with different heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have website and I want to make scroll down button and navigation menu (In fiddle only with circle button). But I have problem with height. I know that I can subtract it from anchor `target.offset.top`, but my navigation menu isn't same height on toggle.

For example normal navigation menu is 125px height, I need to substract 125px, but what I need to do if my toggle navigation menu is 90px height?

I made transparent navigation and blue background for content that you can see better the question.

Here is my fiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17740/

Comment: The navbar is always collapsed when the user scrolls down?

Comment: For this time - Yes. But I need to scroll only 90px height less (navbar container) not all collapsed menu height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your second jQuery part and calculate the needed scroll height like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        // store offset().top in a var
        var $anchor_scroll = $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top;
        // calculate offset().top - 90px
        var $anchor_scroll_calc = $anchor_scroll - 90; 
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $anchor_scroll_calc
        }, 1500);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/DTcHh/17742/)</kbd>

Next you could use `.hasClass` to check wether the `.navbar-fixed-top` is collapsed or not and use a `if {} else {}` function inside the calculation:

```
if( $('.navbar-fixed-top').hasClass('top-nav-collapse')) {
  var $anchor_scroll_calc = $anchor_scroll - 90; 
} else {
  var $anchor_scroll_calc = $anchor_scroll - 120; 
}
```

<kbd>[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/DTcHh/17770/)</kbd>

Comment: Yes it's working perfect on toggle navbar, but I need to do same on not toggled navbar. Heights is different - 120px and 90px;

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try this soon